# Can't get PyAudio working with Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, audio

I've been planning an audio project with my raspberry pi and have played with some ideas using PyAudio on my mac with no trouble.  I just recently set up my RPi and am having some trouble running PyAudio in Raspian.

```
pi@joeyrpi ~/Desktop/pyaudio-repo/pyaudio-test $ uname -a
Linux joeyrpi 3.12.28+ #709 PREEMPT Mon Sep 8 15:28:00 BST 2014 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

Simply running python from the command line and trying to instantiate the pyaudio module dumps a bunch of warnings and then a fatal error and kills the process.

```
import pyaudio
pa = pyaudio.PyAudio()
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.front
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround40
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround41
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround50
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround51
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.surround71
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.iec958
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.iec958
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.iec958
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:957:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) The dmix plugin supports only playback stream
FATAL: cannot locate cpu MHz in /proc/cpuinfo
```

I've seen a few posts around the web from people who have indirectly (other applications crashing) seen the issue and a trying to use pyaudio directly, but they haven't seemed to resolve the problem.  Apparently the cpu mhz field was removed from /proc/cpuinfo and that's what's causing jack to crash.  I've read that it's been patched, but I don't see why I would be still see this error.  Perhaps I need to update the jack packages, though I'm no sure what they are.

I did use the NOOBS installer, so perhaps it hasn't been updated to install the latest Raspbian image.  Can anyone tell me why this issue is still happening and how to resolve it?